# Why is long casted to double in Java?

Tags: java, double, long-integer

**SSCCE:**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Long a = new Long(1L);
        new A(a);
    }

    static class A {
        A(int i) {
            System.out.println("int");
        }

        A(double d) {
            System.out.println("double");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
double
```

There will be no compilation error printed, it works fine and calls `double`-parameter constructor. But **why?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting `long` to `int` is a [narrowing primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) because it can lose the overall magnitude of the value. Converting `long` to `double` is a [widening primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).

The compiler will automatically generate [assignment context](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) conversion for arguments. That includes widening primitive conversion, but not narrowing primitive conversion. Because the method with an `int` argument would require a narrowing conversion, it is not applicable to the call.

Answer (score 9):

It's down to the rules of type promotion: a `long` is converted to a `double` in preference to an `int`.

A `long` can always fit into a `double`, *although* precision *could* be lost if the `long` is larger than the 53rd power of 2. So your compiler picks the `double` constructor as a better fit than the `int` one.

(The compiler doesn't make a *dynamic* check in the sense that `1L` *does* fit into an `int`).

Comment: I understand "fit" thing, I can't get why there is no compilation error?

Comment: You don't get an error since it's not an error. A compiler might warn you though of a potentially lossy conversion.

Comment: For example, in C++ there will be compilation error, if you'd try to put `long long` value to `int` or `double` constructor

Answer (score 2):

`int` is of 4 bytes where as `long` and `double` are of 8 bytes

So, it is quite obvious that there is a chance for loss of 4 bytes of data if it is casted to an int. Datatypes are always up casted. As the comment from @Bathsheba mentioned, there is a chance of data loss even in case of using double, but the loss is much smaller when compared with int.

[image: Double bits]

As you can see, double uses 52 bits for storing significant digits. Where as if it chooses int, the variable will have 32 bits available to it. Hence jvm chooses the double instead of int.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Answer (score 1):

Because a long doesn't "fit" in an int.

Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html